# Kafka Unable to create a basic 3 node cluster on 3 separate VM's

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using kafka version 2.11-2.3.1 and zookeeper 3.4.10-3 and am able to get each of 3 Ubuntu 18.04 VM's running everything fine ***separately*** with basic configs allowing me to create a topic, produce data, and consume data with the kafka provided `kafka-topics.sh`, `kafka-console-producer.sh`, and `kafka-console-consumer.sh`.
Can anyone please help me set up the configs of zookeeper and kafka so that I can connect the 3 into a cluster? I thought all I had to do was set configs as shown below and then use the `kafka-topics.sh` shell scripts to create a topic with replication-factor 3 and then use the `kafka-console-producer.sh` and `kafka-console-consumer.sh` and it would work. But I am getting lots of different errors. Does anyone have a guide/tutorial I can follow?

In `zoo.cfg` the only settings I have changed from the default script are:
For server 1 ...

```
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888                  
server.2=myserver2.com.au:2888:3888
server.3=myserver3.com.au:2888:3888
```

... and similarly for servers 2 and 3

In kafka's `server.properties`, the only settings I have changed from the default are:
For server 1 ...

```
broker.id=1
zookeeper.connect=0.0.0.0:2181,myserver2.com.au:2181,myserver3.com.au:2181
```

... and similarly for servers 2 and 3 (`broker.id` is set to 2 and 3 respectively and the `zookeeper.connect` servers are set appropriately).

Then on `myserver1.com.au` I ran:

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper
    "localhost:2181,myserver2.com.au:2181,myserver3.com.au:2181" 
    --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

and then tried ...

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list
    "localhost:9092,myserver2.com.au:9092,myserver3.com.au:9092" 
    --topic test
```

But it fails with numerous errors. One is ...

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Should not set log start 
    offset on partition test's local replica 1 without attempting 
    to delete records of the log
```

another is...

```
ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Error when handling request: clientId=0, correlationId=0,
    api=UPDATE_METADATA, body={controller_id=0,controller_epoch=1,
    broker_epoch=155,topic_states=[{t...
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Epoch 155 larger than current broker epoch 24
```

another is ...

```
ERROR Error when sending message to topic test4 with key: null, value: 1 bytes with 
    error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in
    metadata after 60000 ms.
```

another is ...

```
ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 1 bytes with 
    error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server 
    is not the leader for that topic-partition.
```

I can't seem to find anything useful on the internet about these errors and I've tried quite a few combinations of things but am really struggling, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Honestly, don't do it manually, unless you just want to learn. Use something like Ansible. https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/cp-ansible.html

Comment: `zookeeper.connect` needs to point to a valid address, not 0.0.0.0 ;

Also, in latest versions of Kafka, you can use `--bootstrap-server` with all commands (maybe except console producer)